# compute a column value base on the column value in previous row and other column in the same row (oracle 11g db)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

My requirement can be demoed as below SQL in MySQL DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `tran_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty1` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `qty2` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
) ;

insert into test values('2019-01-01 10:00:00',1,0);
insert into test values('2019-01-01 10:00:01',2,0);
insert into test values('2019-01-01 10:00:03',0,1);
insert into test values('2019-01-01 10:00:04',0,2);
insert into test values('2019-01-01 10:00:05',1,0);
insert into test values('2019-01-01 10:00:05',3,0);
insert into test values('2019-01-01 10:00:06',0,4);
insert into test values('2019-01-01 10:00:07',0,1);

select tran_date, qty1, qty2, case when qty1=0 then (@total := @total + qty2 ) when qty1<=@total then (@total := @total - qty1)
else  ( @total := 0 ) end  as  qty3
from test , (select @total := 0 ) as T1
order by tran_date;

+---------------------+------+------+------+
| tran_date           | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 |
+---------------------+------+------+------+
| 2019-01-01 10:00:00 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
| 2019-01-01 10:00:01 |    2 |    0 |    0 |
| 2019-01-01 10:00:03 |    0 |    1 |    1 |
| 2019-01-01 10:00:04 |    0 |    2 |    3 |
| 2019-01-01 10:00:05 |    1 |    0 |    2 |
| 2019-01-01 10:00:05 |    3 |    0 |    0 |
| 2019-01-01 10:00:06 |    0 |    4 |    4 |
| 2019-01-01 10:00:07 |    0 |    1 |    5 |
+---------------------+------+------+------+
```

The qty3 column is what i wanted and it should be caculated base on its value in previous row and the value of qty1 and qty2 in the same row. For the first row it's value is always 0.
the rule is:

```
1. if qty1=0, the qty3 = ${qty3_in_previous_row_value} + qty2

2. if qty1 <= ${qty3_in_previous_row_value}, the qty3 = ${qty3_in_previous_row_value} - qty1

3. else, qty3 = 0
```

Above SQL can work in MySQL DB, I'd like to find a SQL in Oracle DB to do the same function. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It would help your question to also show us what the `qty3` column actually looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, I've added the select result for the mysql demo sql to show the expected qty3 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursive query for this problem similar to your MySQL solution:

```sql
-- Your sample data:
WITH test(tran_date, qty1, qty2) as 
  (SELECT '2019-01-01 10:00:00',1,0 from dual union all
   select '2019-01-01 10:00:01',2,0 from dual union all
   select '2019-01-01 10:00:03',0,1 from dual union all
   select '2019-01-01 10:00:04',0,2 from dual union all
   select '2019-01-01 10:00:05',1,0 from dual union all
   select '2019-01-01 10:00:05',3,0 from dual union all
   select '2019-01-01 10:00:06',0,4 from dual union all
   select '2019-01-01 10:00:07',0,1 from dual)
-- Add an index to join actual with prevous row:
   , rn(tran_date, qty1, qty2, rn) AS
  (SELECT tran_date, qty1, qty2, ROWNUM rn FROM test ORDER BY tran_date)
-- Recursive query from here on:
  , rec(tran_date, qty1, qty2, qty3, rn) AS
  (SELECT tran_date, qty1, qty2, 0, rn FROM rn WHERE rn=1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT rn.tran_date, rn.qty1, rn.qty2
        , CASE WHEN rn.qty1=0 THEN rec.qty3 + rn.qty2
               WHEN rn.qty1<=rec.qty3 THEN rec.qty3 - rn.qty1
               ELSE 0
          END
        , rn.rn
     FROM rec
     JOIN rn
     ON rn.rn = rec.rn + 1)
SELECT tran_date, qty1, qty2, qty3 FROM rec
```